# How to get filename of image resource to a textbox?

Tags: c#

I have looked and nothing I am finding is helping me out but I would like to know how to get a filename to a textbox.

Lets say I have a image in the project settings called image1 so the code would be

Properties.Resources.Image;

but I need the Image name to appear in a textbox.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textbox.Text = nameof(Properties.Resources.Image);
```

Comment: OK I got that part working but now I need to get the picturebox to place the image in it . like pb1.image = properties.resources. textboxname   is there a way to achieve this as well?

Comment: that should work pb1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image;

Comment: yes that does but I am referring to loading the image back into the PB box. like in the textbox I now have image.jpg and I want to use that to load it back so so something like Properties.Resources. textbox1.text;   instead of image;

Comment: I just have to think it though and figure what I am missing.  I could be not explain it right either so that's why you might not understand. but let me try to go in more detail.
you can view a image in a picturebox like this pbox.image = properties.resources.image;  but instead of using image at the enter I want to add whats in the textbox to it. so if the textbox has myfile.jpg then it would be properties.resources.myfile.jpg when ran

Comment: try that :             pb1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(textbox1.text);

Comment: ok no errors but the pb box is blank so should I get rid of the .jpg perhaps?

Comment: I had to use                     txtpath.Text = Convert.ToString(Properties.Resources.myimage);
 instead of the textbox.text = nameof code above because I didn't have nameof in context

Comment: for nameof you need .Net 4 and higher

Comment: but Convert.ToString(Properties.Resources.myimage) will give you System.Drawing.Bitmap instade of the name

Comment: if you are referring to net framework I am using 4.5.2

Comment: "nameof" is a new operator from C# 6. Its not about Net framework. Youll need VS2015 or newer to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

create a static class and add this

`public static string GetNameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
        {
            return (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        }`

then use it like this

`var s = Nameofstaticclass.GetNameOf(() => Properties.Resources.image1);`